# Should I title my article to match search keywords or to best match the content?

Tags: seo, keywords

I selected one keyword for an article of my site: "Best baby stroller"

After couple of days later, I found another word is more appropriate with this article: "Best car sit baby stroller"

But this keyword has very little search volume.

Can I do rank for "Best baby stroller" by targeting "Best car sit baby stroller" as my primary keyword?

Comment: Pages can rank for an unlimited amount of search terms. Because those two are so similar it is very plausible it can rank for both. Especially if one is not a commonly used phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Search is not about keywords and has not been since 1997 when Google came onto the scene as a semantics based search engine. Granted, when Google was new, implementation of semantics was far less sophisticated than it is now. Today, the implementation of semantics is staggering and far more complex than ever imagined or even realized by SEOs to this day. The notion of keywords is derived from the highlighting of search terms found in search results after very many algorithms have been applied. This effect is incidental and not actual. At no point does Google make term matches. This is especially true with the introduction of RankBrain which has always existed to some lesser level. So please, ignore the SEOs that take about keywords and throw this notion out of your mind forever.

What works are complete and descriptive sentences and not keywords.

To focus on keywords is to miss the point. What happens when a site owner focuses on keywords is to skew the semantic results narrowing how their site is actually found to a far narrower search market.

Be that as it may.

The difference between *Best baby stroller* and *Best car sit baby stroller* and an understanding of semantics makes it clear that only one is preferred. But let me make a correction to your phrase *Best car sit baby stroller* first. It is more correct to use *Best car seat baby stroller*. Primarily, sit is a verb and seat is a noun and the association between car, sit, and baby will be mistaken for the action of *a baby sitting in a car* rather than a description of your product.

Let me go further. *Best car seat baby stroller* has *Best baby stroller* within it. Semantically speaking the first is stronger the the second.

Clear?

When trying to rank pages for search, it is always best to be natural, however, it is also best to also be descriptive and provide as many clues to your product as is reasonably possible. This can be spread through out your content.

I use the question What about...?. For example, what about car seat, baby stroller? What is important for you to say about your product? What are people looking for? What concerns do people have? What is popular? What is often missed?

Search is not about search trends. These mostly only apply to trend based sites such as celebrity news sites. Instead, you want to tap into not what search engines say are trending, but what the user is looking for, is concerned about, does not know, needs to know, what others say, etc. Following keywords and trend searches will only drive you away from the so-called long-tail search potential.

For example, it may not advantage you to use the term *best*. Who is searching for *best car seat*? Is it that anyone who is searching for the best car seat is using the term *quality*, *safest*, etc.? If you are writing content such as *The DXP brand child car seat meets and exceeds AAA safety standards making it the safest child car seat available today.*, then you will likely see better search results.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that "search is not about keywords and has not been since 1997"?

Comment: Yeah. Googles patents.

Comment: Which ones? Their 2009 patent _"Determining query term synonyms within query context"_ (US Patent 7636714) says "The search engine assigns a score to each document based on the document's page rank (and/or other query-independent measure of the document's importance), as well as one or more query-dependent signals of the document's importance (**e.g., the location and frequency of search terms in the document**).

Comment: @GDav That is true, however, that is not how search terms are satisfied which is my point. It is not a matter of direct keyword matches and never has been. The original research paper describes a term based index where semantics is applied, albeit in a far less sophisticated way. Google is not term based but topic based. It is impossible to understand content and search intent with just a few keywords, however, it is relatively using linguistic semantics. Along hey way, Google has had more or less success in this area, however, they have gotten much better.

Comment: @GDav RankBrain is simply applying semantics to the search query in much the same way that semantics is applied in the index. It is like moving the back end of an elephant after you move the front. It just makes sense.

Comment: @GDav BTW- it is not necessary to use synonyms in your content to inform Google that the terms apply. This is done automatically within the index. Instead, in another answer somewhere, I explain how synonyms can help strengthen the semantic score for a piece of content. BTW- it is not good to quote too much from older patents. The 2009 patent may be there to cover what they have done in the past. Around 2009/10, Google changed the structure of their index away from the term index where POS (term relative position in semantics) was only one of a few semantic clues they had.

Comment: I quote a 2009 patent because it talks about search term occurrences in the document as a ranking signal; something you claim hasn't happened since 1997. The patent I referenced is referred to in a later (2013) Google patent, _"Synonym identification based on co-occurring terms"_, which at least one patent researcher has pointed to as the basis for the Hummingbird algorithm. This suggests continued relevance. Back to my original question: can you point to any specific patents that support your claim?

Comment: @GDav You will notice that the patent covers what the original research paper says. Keep in mind that Google does not want to give away the store by telling people what the are up to. Some patents are filed late to protect what they *have* done and not what they *are* doing. Beginning in 2008, Google began moving it's model away from the old model to a new model based in part upon what they learned in scholar which as more semantic based. Given that, it is possible that part of the old model still exists, however, Google never made direct term matches.

Comment: @GDav What you are quoting is in part how semantics was handled with the original forward and reverse term index where the POS value (position of the term from the beginning of the page/content) is used to recreate semantic relationships between terms for analysis. Today, Google uses the HTML DOM model with specific IDs and full semantic analysis of the DOM objects in matrices of various size and overlap to weigh and make query matches. Term density is used in semantics analysis as only one factor of many and does not add weight to any specific term but rather content topic overall.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rank for a phrase it is no longer enough to create a page with that title and link to it.   That was a valid SEO strategy 8 years ago, but it won't get you anywhere today.

Keywords still matter, but exact match titles don't matter anymore.   I'd still try to title the article in ways to get the searched keywords towards the front.   You could try something like:

> Best Baby Stroller that Converts to a Car Seat

If you really want to rank for "best baby stroller", you need more than just the article you have written.     One strategy might be to create an entire series of articles:

- Best Baby Strollers for Jogging
- Best Baby Strollers for Infants
- Best Baby Strollers for Twins
- Best Baby Stroller with an Older Child
- etc.

The bottom line is that your content has to be compelling compared to the other content available that matches that search term.   It must:

- Be in depth
- Use the correct keywords
- Use proper grammar and spelling
- Give users the answer they are looking for
- Attract clicks when Google experiments with ranking it
- Satisfy users so they don't come back to the results and click on something else
- Attract links from other websites and shares on social media